# Does C prefer a (void) arglist in a C function implementation?

Tags: c

I know that that there's a difference in the following two functions *declarations*:

```
int foo1();
int foo2(void);
```

because that says `foo1()` can accept any number of arguments while `foo2()` accepts no arguments.

But for the *implementation*, does the C language spec prefer one of the following?

```
int foo2() { return 2; }
int foo2(void) { return 2; }
```

In other words, is it appropriate to include `void` in the otherwise empty parameter list?

Comment: Your *implementations* of `foo2()` are equivalent. The first, however, does not provide a prototype **to the compiler** making its use more problematic.

Comment: I am not sure the marked duplicate if answering this question. The answer there is not addressing the definition `int foo()` *with* a prototype `int foo(void)`. Or maybe it is not the question?

Comment: A function without a prototype is a regular function that accepts a specific number of arguments, each with its specific type. However that information is not available to the compiler, the programmer has to get it right (or suffer UB). A function with `...` accepts a variable number of arguments, with varying types.

Comment: The marked duplicate answers this question completely.  Whether `int foo()` is preferable to `int foo(void)` depends on whether or not you believe the compiler should *check for the absence of arguments in function calls.*

Comment: The marked duplicate makes it sound like `int foo() {return 23;}` _should_ tell the compiler to reject arguments in subsequent calls to foo, but all the compilers I can conveniently test do _not_ reject arguments in subsequent calls to foo.  This might just mean that the accepted answer to the duplicate is wrong, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I read the marked duplicate and it does not answer what happens with `void foo(void);` declaration followed by `void foo() {...}` definition.  Do you agree?

Comment: The `void foo(void)` fails to compile if you try to call it with any arguments.  If you try that with `void foo()`, it will compile and then produce undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that some compilers will warn you, but then produce the correct behavior anyway.  See https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/Empty-parameter-lists-in-C

Comment: @RobertHarvey I specifically wasn't asking about _calling_ the function.  Just about the definition.  The marked duplicate doesn't address that.  Methinks it's time to re-ask the improved question.  (You can vote it down! :)

Comment: The definition is of no consequence unless you actually use the function by *calling* it.

Comment: I vote to close this question in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517172/definition-of-int-foo-vs-int-foovoid-following-declaration-of-int